# EOFException using readObject() deserializing an ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, serialization

I'm trying to serialize an instance from a class using inheritance.

And this is the class where I try to serialize the data

```
public class Serializacion {

    static int agregarProfeTitular(ProfesorTitular p){
        int status = 0;

        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("profestitulares.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
            ArrayList pi = conseguirTodosProfesTitulares();

            pi.add(p);
            oos.writeObject(pi);
            oos.close();
            fos.close();

            status = 1;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error al agregar el prof titular..."+Arrays.toString(e.getStackTrace()));
        }

        return status;
    }

    static ArrayList<ProfesorTitular> conseguirTodosProfesTitulares(){
        ArrayList<ProfesorTitular> pi = new ArrayList<ProfesorTitular>();

        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("profestitulares.txt");
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

            pi = (ArrayList<ProfesorTitular>) ois.readObject();

            ois.close();
            fis.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error al conseguir a los profes titulares..."+e);
        }

        return pi;
    }

}
```

At the end the try-catch throws me

```
java.io.EOFException
at java.io.ObjectInputStream$BlockDataInputStream.peekByte(ObjectInputStream.java:2950)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1534)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:427)
at profesores.Serializacion.conseguirTodosProfesTitulares(Serializacion.java:69)
at profesores.Serializacion.agregarProfeTitular(Serializacion.java:46)
```

The idea is that when I want to write some data in my file first I get the data that already exists parsing it as an arraylist and then i return that arraylist and i just add the new data. It works writing the file, but reading it doesnt work.

EDIT:

This is the class code that I try to serialize:

```
public class ProfesorTitular extends Profesor {

    int horasBase;

    public ProfesorTitular(int id, String nombre, String clase, int horasBase) {
        super(id, nombre, clase);
        this.horasBase = horasBase;
    }

    public int getHorasBase() {
        return horasBase;
    }

    public void setHorasBase(int horasBase) {
        this.horasBase = horasBase;
    }


}
```

Comment: Perhaps you could include the error that's being thrown in your question.  It would also be a good idea to show some implementation of `ProfesorTitular` in order to allow people to run your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You create a `FileOutputStream` for the very poorly named file `profestitulares.txt`. Serialized data is not text and should not be saved in files with the .txt extension.
2. This creates an empty file.
3. You then create an `ObjectOutputStream` around this stream, which writes the object stream header.
4. You then create a `FileInputStream` for the same file, which is now empty apart from the object stream header, whatever its state may have previously been.
5. You then try to create an `ObjectInputStream` around this, which fails, because there is a stream header but no objects in this logically empty file.

Solution: read the objects from the file before you create the new one.